# Why b transforms in another number?

Tags: c, calculator

Why when I run this code b in the end transforms to 1410065408?
But 1 step before b was 100000000000 and it should be the same
(It's calculator from dec form to binnar)

P.S. all program steps I watched in [C visualize](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binnar(int a){

    long long int b = 0, x = 1;
    while(a != 0){
        b += (a % 2) * x;
        x *= 10;
        a = a/2;
    }
    return b;
}

void main(){
    int a = 1024;
    printf("%lld", binnar(a));
}
```

I expect that b will be 100000000000, not 1410065408

Comment: `100000000000` is to big for a 32 bit int.

Comment: PSA: Don't use types like `long long int` that can be confusing, instead use `int64_t` which is completely unambiguous.

Comment: @Potter What type is `b`? What type does the function return? And what's the correct format specifier for an `int`?

Comment: You have 'correctly' used `long long int` types *inside* your function (notwithstanding the comment from tadman) but then you lose all that effort by returning a plain `int`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Aside: `main()` should return an `int`.

Comment: make the result string. Saving it as decimal which *looks* like binary is quite meaningless and confusing.

Comment: `%lld` is wrong for `int`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `int binnar(int a){`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what does the `int` part mean? Will it be possible to `return` a value like `100000000000` from this function? Why or why not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

% is the modulo operator (returns the remainder)

What happens here is

a=1024, a%2=0, x=1, b=0

a=512, a%2=0, x=10, b=0 (b is not incremented because a%2 is 0)

and it continues until

a=1, a%2=1, x=100000000000 BUT because the return type of binnar is an int, it does not work the way you want it to, and it overflows. Try changing the return type of binnar to a long long and see if it works as you intend.

edit: added code

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long int binnar(int a){

    long long int b = 0, x = 1;
    while(a != 0){
        b += (a % 2) * x;
        x *= 10;
        a = a/2;
    }
    return b;
}

void main(){
    int a = 1024;
    printf("%lld", binnar(a));
}
```